# Why am i getting null even after instanstiating a class?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, object

I basically have two classes namely `A` and `MOC`.

When i call `HCAA()->get_moc()` i don't get the class but instead i get null. Why is this happening ?

```
final class A {

    private $moc;


    private function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
    }


    public static function instance() {
        static $instance;

        if( ! isset($instance) ) {
            $instance = new A();
        }

        return $instance;
    }


    public function init() {
        if ( is_admin() && current_user_can('manage_options') ) { 
            $this->plugin_start();  
        }
    }


    private function plugin_start(){
        $this->moc = new MOC();
        var_dump($this->moc);
    }


    public function get_moc(){
        return $this->moc;
    }

}



class MOC{

    private $moc;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'customize_register', array($this, 'customize_register'), 12 );
    }

    public function customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
      $this->moc = $wp_customize;
    }

    public function add( $options ) {
        var_dump('add called');
    }

}

function HCAA() {
    return A::instance();
}
```

i am initially calling the `HCAA` function like this.

```
HCAA();
```

Plus i am also getting this error.

> **PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function add() on a non-object in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/hc-moc/utils/test.php on line 47**

Comment: Maybe you're calling the function too early, since the `$moc` property is defined in `plugin_start()` which is hooked to `init` , try calling the function after `init` hook and see if it works

Comment: You're right i was hooking too late in the init hook.